# An arithmetic hierarchy without bounded quantifiers

Tags: number-theory, logic, formal-languages

Let $\exists_n$ formulas in the language of arithmetic be defined like $\Sigma_n$ formulas, except that bounded quantifiers count toward the number of quantifier alternations. For example, $\exists_1$ formulas are purely existential formulas, those of the form $\exists \bar{y} \phi(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$, where $\phi$ is quantifier-free.

My first question is the following:

> For all $n \ge 1$, are all $\Sigma_n$ formulas equivalent to $\exists_n$ formulas, in the sense that if $\phi$ is $\Sigma_n$, then there is a $\exists_n$ formula $\psi$ such that $\mathbb{N} \models \forall \bar{x} (\phi(\bar{x}) \leftrightarrow \psi(\bar{x}))$?

Following on from this is my second question:

> Can we even have $\mathrm{PA} \vdash \forall \bar{x} (\phi(\bar{x}) \leftrightarrow \psi(\bar{x}))$, where $\mathrm{PA}$ is Peano arithmetic?

It's easy to see that the answer is negative for $n = 0$, and for $n=1$ the answer is affirmative by the MRDP theorem.

Comment: Isn't it clear that all $\exists_n$ formulas are $\Sigma_n$? I think you meant to ask about the converse.

Comment: You're right. I fixed the question.